# Bigquery Java API returns Billing Tier as a BigDecimal

Tags: java, google-bigquery

I Have been using the Java Bigquery API to get the Billing Tier for our Bigquery jobs. I was wondering why the API has been designed to return a BigDecimal for the billing tier when the value can only be 1,2 or 3. Why not just use an `int`?


[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of answer can be given here.... "because the devs put it in a BigDecimal"? Maybe at first it was supposed to be MORE than just 1-2-3 and they never changed it back?

Answer (score 3):

The BigDecimal that you see here is an internal implementation detail about how the Java client translates fields from the raw json response. It uses a map of key name to 'Object' value.

The Java Client is automatically generated from the API definition [here](https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest).  My guess is that it stores the value as a `BigDecimal` because if the underlying type were an unsigned 64-bit value, this cannot be represented in java, since the highest bit would get interpreted as a negative value. So it considers all numeric fields `BigDecimals` underneath the covers.

That said, when you actually go to read the value, the Java [API](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/bigquery/model/JobStatistics2.html#getBillingTier()) to get that field returns a Java `Integer`, not a `BigDecimal`. So as far as using the object is concerned, it shouldn't matter how the data is stored.

If you download the client library [here](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/download/bigquery/v2/java), you can read the source yourself (unzip the result, and look in google-api-services-bigquery-v2-rev237-1.20.0-sources.jar).